# Site não esta scrollando (rolando a tela) no google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debug

Boa tarde! Estou fazendo a manutenção de um site: https://editora-arara-azul.com.br e quando acesso do google chrome o site não esta rolando a pagina. Mas quando uso qualquer outro navegador funciona normalmente. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
( O Scroll só não funciona no navegador Google Chrome) 
Tem alguma coisa haver com o overflow?

Comment: Checou o console e viu os erros ?

Comment: Vi sim Pedro, não esta apresentando erro algum no console.